# sitemap for android deep linking

Tags: android, sitemap, deep-linking

This may be a stupid question because I am not doing a good job reading the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html). I am trying to implement deep linking for my android app. I have an app engine backend (with no website client). Reading the documentations it says

> you can allow Googlebot to crawl the content in the APK through the
>   Google Play Store to index the app content.

So my basic understanding of this line is that I have to create a "site map" and package it with my `.apk`. Is this correct? If so, how do I do that? As in does someone have a short example and some instructions such as where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to support a 'site map' for your .apk is to include the following snippet so Google's Googlebot can index your apk, and open your app if someone clicks on your content:

`<link rel="alternate" href="/* your full URI path here */"/>`

You'd need to inject this inside your .html pages on your website, that link up with your HTTP deep links on Android.

You could also use an open-source service like [Branch](http://branch.io?bmp=stackoverflow) and have them automatically generate said 'sitemap' for your Android deeplinks and .apk.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by html page as I already mention there is no web client. My app-engine api serves json. That's all. Each endpoint returns a json.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Android App Indexing requires that you have a website that mimics the content of your App, so that Google can crawl and validate that same content.

Regarding your case, for your App content to be discovered by Google, you must fill in this app-only interest form (https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/app-only).
However, filling up this form does not guarantee you that Google will index your App content, but it's a start.

Hope it helps.